# Javascript twitter monitoring + discord webhooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, twitter

I have a ready-made code to monitor twitter, but there is no task of monitoring individual accounts. I also need to add integration to the discord using webhooks. I also have code, but it does not work

```
const Twit = require('twit')
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
const open = require('open');
const franc = require('franc')

const apikey = 'xxx'
const apiSecretKey = 'xxx'
const accessToken = 'xxx'
const accessTokenSecret = 'xxx'

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         apikey,
  consumer_secret:      apiSecretKey,
  access_token:         accessToken,
  access_token_secret:  accessTokenSecret,
});

(async () => {

    // //1. GET RECENT TWEETS
    // T.get('search/tweets', { q: '#tesla since:2020-04-15', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
    //   const tweets = data.statuses
    //   // .map(tweet => `LANG: ${franc(tweet.text)} : ${tweet.text}`) //CHECK LANGUAGE
    //   .map(tweet => tweet.text)
    //   .filter(tweet => tweet.toLowerCase().includes('elon'));
    //   console.log(tweets);
    // })

    // //2. REAL TIME MONITORING USING STREAM (HASHTAG)
    // var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#tesla' })
    // stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
    //     console.log(tweet.text);
    //     console.log('Language: ' + franc(tweet.text));
    //     console.log('------');
    // })

    // 3. REAL TIME MONITORING USING STREAM (LOCATION)
    var sanFrancisco = [ '-122.75', '36.8', '-121.75', '37.8' ]
    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { locations: sanFrancisco })





//DISCORD WEBHOOK
//const sendDiscordMessage = (pl) => {
    //const {content,turl} = pl;
    //const {name,webhook,avatar_url} = THandlers.filter((d,i) => d.url === turl)[0];
    //request.post(webhook).form({username:name,avatar_url:avatar_url,content:content});
}
```

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Agree twitter monitor

Comment: Hey, take a look at this: https://github.com/signicode/meetjs-luty/blob/master/simple-status.js - I made this some time ago.